# Why does Javascript generate "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined" if this property is defined?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game using html5 and javascript. The file is a version of "space invaders." I have a function which checks if a laser beam comes into contact with an enemy. However, when a laser beam is created the following error is generated:

```
index.html:94 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getTopY' of 
undefined at laserCollision (index.html:94)
```

The laserCollision() function:

```
function laserCollision() {
    for(var i = enemyArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for(var j = playerLaserBeamsArray.length-1; j >= 0; j++) {
            // make sure not to access an object which does not exist.
            if(playerLaserBeamsArray[j] == 'undefined') break;
            // check if laser beam is at correct y coordinate
            if(playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getTopY() > enemyArray[i].getY() && playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getBottomY() < enemyArray[i].getY()) {
            // check if laser beam is between the enemy's furthermost left and right x-coordinates
            if(playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getLeftX() <= enemyArray[i].getLeftX() && playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getRightX() <= enemyArray[i].getRightX()){
                   score ++;
                   enemyArray[i].splice(i, 1);
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

The game can be played at:
https://ruben-krueger.github.io/Interstellar-Invaders/

And the github repo is at:
https://github.com/Ruben-Krueger/Interstellar-Invaders

Comment: The **string constant** `'undefined'` is not the same as the value `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

You've written:

```
for(var j = playerLaserBeamsArray.length-1; j >= 0; j++)
```

so, your "j" would grow unlimited. It seems, that you've wanted to write "j--" not "j++".

Next:

```
playerLaserBeamsArray[j].getTopY()
```

as j grows to the infinity, soon playerLaserBeamsArray[j] became undefined, bacause your array index is out of range.